# Macro broken after upgrade to 4.10

Tags: razor, umbraco

I recently upgraded from 4.09 to Umbraco 4.10.  I have a pretty common/simple little macro that I use to generate my top navigation.  I check the record to see if it's the last in the count, and if not add a pipe symbol as a visual separator.
This worked as expected with all version thru 4.09 but after upgrade all item get the pipe symbol even the last one.

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

@{ 
  var level = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Parameter.Level) ? 1 : int.Parse(Parameter.Level); 
  var ulClass = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Parameter.UlClass) ? "" : String.Format(" class=\"{0}\"", Parameter.UlClass); 
  var parent = @Model.AncestorOrSelf(level);
  var pages = parent.Children.Where("Visible");
  if (parent != null) {
    <ul class="topNav">
    @foreach (var item in pages) {
        var selected = Array.IndexOf(Model.Path.Split(','), item.Id.ToString()) >= 0 ? " class=\"selected\"" : "";
        if (item != (pages.Last()))
        {
          <li@Html.Raw(selected)>
            <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name |</a>
          </li>
        }
        else
        {
           <li@Html.Raw(selected)>
            <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
          </li>
        }
      }
    </ul>
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what changed, but it seems like (in my code) pages.Last() is never true.
Anyone have any ideas?  - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the result you want by using the `IsNotLast()` helper, like so:

```
<li@Html.Raw(selected)>
    <a href="@item.url">@item.Name@(item.IsNotLast() ? " |" : "")</a>
</li>
```

Refer to the [Umbraco Razor Feature Walkthrough–Part 7](http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2011/9/18/umbraco-razor-feature-walkthrough%E2%80%93part-7.aspx) for more information on the IsHelpers that are available. They're pretty handy when you want information about the nodes you're traversing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going at it a little bit differently, but I still have no idea why this changed.

instead of

> if (item != (pages.Last()))

I went with

> if (item.Index() != (pages.Count()-1))

solved for now, but I welcome any feedback if anyone else stumbles on this issue

Comment: Douglas Ludlow's answer above was much better than this ugly band-aid